# PipeDrive - how to avoid loops when using WebHooks?

Tags: python, django, pipedrive-api

I'm working with `PipeDrive` API and I've started to use their webhooks. 
The problem is that it cause loops.

Simple example:

There is a model `Deal` which has two methods - `Deal.sync()`, `Deal.backsync()`

`Deal.sync()` sends updated or created `Deal` object to the `PipeDrive`
`Deal.backsync()` fetches  `Deal` object from the `PipeDrive`

But the problem is that when I call `sync`, the `Deal` object is sent to the `PipeDrive` which invokes `webhook` so my server receives this `webhook` and automatically invokes `Deal.backsync()` etc.

I have some ideas but maybe there is some elegant way I don't know. Ideally, for example `sync` would send some `uuid` which would be sent in `webhook` so I know it was caused by `sync`.

Do you know how to make this work?

Comment: not sure if this is still an issue for you, but to deal with this in the past I've had to use some sort of storage option or custom field on the PipeDrive object as state to prevent endless loops. If the service is stateful, I would have my webhook update/check local state if it has processed a change before - same concept with using a custom field, store timestamps/info about the cause.